# How to filter out elements of certain data types in a vector of std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, stdset, std-variant

I have a `std::vector` of `std::variant` elements with type `int` or `std::set<int>`. I want to loop over this vector and `insert` an extra item if the iterated element is of type `std::set<int>`. However, it seems that querying the index at run-time is not allowed. How can I achieve this?

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using Variants = std::variant<int, std::set<int>>;

    std::vector<Variants> var_vec;
    var_vec.push_back(999);
    std::set<int> a = {0,1,2};
    var_vec.push_back(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < var_vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        // if the element var_vec[i] is of type std::set<int>
        if (var_vec[i].index() == 1) var_vec[i].insert(888);   // !ERROR! How to achieve this?
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
error: '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::variant<int, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::variant<int, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >::value_type' {aka 'class std::variant<int, std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> > >'} has no member named 'insert'
```

Comment: `var_vec[i].insert` is the problem, not `index`

Comment: I wonder if [std::holds_alternative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative) could help you here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with calling `index()` at runtime, this happens all the time. The real problem is:

```
var_vec[i].insert(888);
```

`var_vec[i]` is a `std::variant`. It does not have a method called `insert()`.

```
std::get<1>(var_vec[i]).insert(888);
```

This gives you the variant's set, which will happily allow you to `insert()` something.

One problem with this overall approach is that if you, for some reason, want to modify your variant, and that `std::set` is no longer its 2nd alternative, for some reason, all of the above logic will break again.

You should consider [using `std::holds_alternative`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative), instead of `index()`, and [using a type with `std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) instead of an index, which will automatically adapt to this kind of a change.

Comment: Can you please show an example how to use ```std::holds_alternative``` and ```std::get()``` by modifying the sample code I provided? THX.

Comment: Just use `std::holds_alternative<std::set<int>>()` and `std::get<std::set<int>>()`. This is fully explained in the links I provided, with many examples, and there should be more examples in every advanced C++ textbook. Is there something specific in the linked reference documentation, or a textbook, on this subject that's unclear?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to loop over this vector and insert an extra item if the iterated element is of type std::set. However, it seems that querying the index at run-time is not allowed. How can I achieve this?

You don't *need* to check the type at runtime, you could just use [`std::visit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) and check if the variant's type is `std::set<int>` at compile-time:

```cpp
// Others headers go here...
#include <type_traits>

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < var_vec.size(); ++i)
    // if the element var_vec[i] is of type std::set<int>
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>, std::set<int>>)
            arg.insert(888);
    }, var_vec[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The filtering can be done via `ranges::views::filter`, and we can use `std::visit` to make up a predicate.

To do so we need to feed `std::visit` with a predicate on the types. A predicate on types can be made up as a set of overlaoded functions that each takes a type and all return a `bool`; you can create it via `boost::hana::overload`.

However, to filter the variants we need to feed `std::visit` only with its first argument, and to leave its second parameter free; one way to do it is to wrap `std::visit` in a nested lambda, like this:

```cpp
    auto visit_with = [](auto const& fs){
      return [&fs](auto const& xs) {
        return std::visit(fs, xs);
      };
    };
```

Another way is to use [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html) and `boost::hana::curry` the result to make it partially applicabale, which is all done in one line:

```cpp
    auto visit_with = curry<2>(BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::visit));
```

Here's the complete code:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
using namespace boost::hana;
using namespace ranges::views;
int main()
{
    using Variants = std::variant<int, std::set<int>>;

    std::vector<Variants> var_vec;
    var_vec.push_back(999);
    std::set<int> a = {0,1,2};
    var_vec.push_back(a);

    // predicate
    auto constexpr true_for_sets = overload(
          [](std::set<int> const&){ return true; },
          [](auto const&){ return false; });

    // function object wrapping std::visit
    auto visit_with = curry<2>(BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::visit));

    // filter
    auto var_vec_out = var_vec | filter(visit_with(true_for_sets));
}
```

And this is all about the filtering you mention in the title. However, in the body of the question, you're not actually doing a filtering, but something else, as you are modifying the set as you traverse it.

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed out you're calling `insert` on an `std::variant` and not the `std::set`.

One approach I'd use is using `std::get_if` like so:

```
#include <variant>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main( ) {
    using Variants = std::variant<int, std::set<int>>;

    std::vector<Variants> var_vec;    
    var_vec.push_back(999);
    std::set<int> a = {0,1,2};
    var_vec.push_back(a);

    for ( auto& v : var_vec ) {    
        // If the variant does not hold a set, get_if returns a nullptr.    
        if ( auto set{ std::get_if<std::set<int>>( &v ) } ) {
            set->insert( 888 );
        }
    }
    // Or you could use holds_alternative with get, but this isn't as clean.
    for ( auto& v : var_vec ) {        
        if ( std::holds_alternative<std::set<int>>( v ) ) {
            auto set{ std::get<std::set<int>>( v ) };
            set.insert( 999 );
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to both test for the type and use the contained alternative.